# Automatic Resizing Function

Tags: javascript, html, css, resize

So I have a bar that contains many smaller divs inside it, each with the same class.

```css
.outer-bar{
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.outer-bar button {
  width: 50px;
  height: 40px;
  outline: none;
  background-color: white;
  border: none;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class = "outer-bar">
  <button class = "a">Hi</button>
  <button class = "a">Hi</button>
  <button class = "a">Hi</button>
  <button class = "a">Hi</button>
  <button class = "a">Hi</button>
  <button class = "a">Hi</button>
  <button class = "a">Hi</button>
  <button class = "a">Hi</button>
  <button class = "a">Hi</button>
</div>
```

When the window resized, I want the window to only show enough of them that there is no overflow, but there is as many as there can be.

So using: `window.addEventListener("resize", function() {} );`, is there any way to implement that?

One great example I saw was on [Google Docs](https://docs.new), where their bar automatically adjusts.

I would prefer doing this with Javascript and CSS and no Jquery or external libaries. (Note that I simplified the widths and number of elements for illustration purposes although the basic idea is still the same). I also prefer the use of for loops and `document.getElementsByClassName("a")`.

I already started it by using:

```
var ribbon = document.getElementsByClassName("outer-bar")[0];
var prevChild = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < ribbon.children.length; i++) {
    if(ribbon.children[i].getBoundingClientRect().right < prevChild) {
        for(var c = i; c < ribbon.children.length; c++) {
            ribbon.children[c].style.display = "none";
        }
        break;
    }
    prevChild = ribbon.children[i].getBoundingClientRect().right;
}
```

Although that method does not make the children displayable once I resize the window to be bigger.

Comment: If you know ribbon length why not divide it by the size you want the button to be. Then loop through the buttons making the first ones(ribbon length/size) block and the rest none.

Comment: sure mark it correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know ribbon length why not divide it by the size you want the button to be. Then loop through the buttons making the first ones(ribbon length/size) block and the rest none.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand you right, but it looks like you need to do a different styling to the inner divs when the screen resizes. CSS is capable of handling this for you without needing to use JavaScript at all.

`Media Queries` let you specify different styling based on the current size of the window.

```
.outer-bar button {
  width: 50px;
  height: 40px;
  outline: none;
  background-color: white;
  border: none;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 2px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .outer-bar button {
    /* 
    Specify here any different styling 
    Ex. 
    */

    width: 25px;
   }
}
```